# Animate text programmatically

Tags: video, animation, rendering

I'd like to create some animated text (simple animations: fade in, fade out, etc...).
I'd like to be able to give the application a UTF-8 string and it spits out and animated video (avi, mpeg, etc...). The format is a little loose at the moment, so if it could handle multiple formats that would be best.

I've googled around quite a bit and mostly all I come up with is flash and animated gifs.
Does anyone know of such an application (open source preferred, but free or commercial would also be fine)?
I was thinking I might be able to put something together with ffmpeg, but I'm not really sure where to begin with the animation piece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

povray animation and ffmpeg did the trick in case anyone else is looking for a similar solution.